# Where do the fragments at the end of Barbie come from?

Tags: production, barbie

At the end of *Barbie*, when Barbie meets Ruth,

> and has a choice of becoming human

she is shown a number of fragments of what seem to be home movies.

Are they indeed fragments of existing home movies? If so, where do they come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sourced from the film's cast and crew.

> Gerwig herself admits “sometimes these movies can have a quality of hegemonic capitalism” and she had to find ways to make the movie her own. She wove in footage of the cast and crew’s friends and family, including images Robbie has filmed herself on a Super 8 over the years, to give the film a personal touch. It’s a home movie smack-dab in the heart of a summer blockbuster, and Gerwig cries every time she watches that part. “It’s like sneaking in humanity to something that everybody thinks is a hunk of plastic.”
>
> [Time Magazine - How Barbie Came to Life](https://time.com/6289864/barbie-time-cover-story/)

Comment: +1, but I guess I don't see how incorporating people's personal lives into a mass-market media product is in opposition to the hegemony of capitalism. Isn't the hegemony of an idea a function of all aspects of life being swept up into it, and so the hegemony of capitalism would be the idea that everything is a product to be commercialized?

Comment: @Obie2.0 - I expect it's the sort of thing she tells herself to convince herself that she isn't a sellout.